# How to stop rotating sub child in u nity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, freeze

I have three game objects A, B and C. A is the parent of B and B is the parent of C. A is rigidbody and main moving object. B is non rigid transform object which rotates from 0,0,0 to 0,0,45 constantly. I want that when When B rotates the B's child C also rotate but its local y axis must be 0 (locked). For example each wiper of old school buses have also a sub wiper when main wiper moves, the sub wiper also moves bus its axis remains vertical. Thats what i want. Plz any body help...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to simply have the C object update its rotation so that `transform.up` is always the same value.

```
Vector3 upDir;

void Awake() 
{
    upDir = transform.up;
}

void Update()
{
    transform.up = upDir;
}
```

If you're interested in keeping its rotation the same as the grandparent, just set its rotation to be equal to that of the grandparent:

```
transform aTransform;

void Awake()
{
    aTransform = transform.parent.parent;
}

void Update()
{
    transform.rotation = aTransform.rotation;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't handle scenarios where OP wants the SubWiper to rotate, or rotate with the grandparent object (skipping the direct parent).

Comment: @ErikOverflow OP is specifically asking about "When B rotates the B's child C also rotate but its local y axis must be 0 (locked). " which is what this answer solves. Just in case, I've edited my answer to address that.

Comment: but the problem is when i move my car or turn my car (grand parent) left or right the "C" also rotates on y axis.

Comment: @AwaisAhmed Sure, so if you want both the direction of the y axis and the rotation of the y axis to be the same as the parent, then just do `transform.rotation = aTransform.rotation;`...

Comment: @Ruzihm Thank You V V Much for your kind time.    transform.rotation = aTransform.rotation; has solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Consider attaching the following to a script to your wiper blade:

```
Vector3 desiredRotation;

void Update()
{
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(desiredRotation + new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, transform.parent.rotation.z * -1.0f));
}
```

This changes the child's rotation to the opposite of the parent's. If the main wiper moves 90 degrees, the subwiper would rotate -90 degrees to counter it.

If you want to rotate your SubWiper in addition to this, you would modify the desiredRotation.

**This solution allows you to "ignore" the direct parent's rotation, but you would still follow the rotation of grandparent.** If you had windshield wipers on a car, if the car flipped upside down, the subwiper shouldn't stay fixed upwards, but should still rotate with the car. The car is the *grandparent*.